# Controlling the Slider Value changed event in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events, slider

I have one child window in Silverlight 3.0 Application. In that application I have one Slider. Whenever I am sliding the slider, The Slider_ValueChanged event gets fire more than 30 times in a second. I want to control the number of events fired? I am using Slider like this:

`<Slider Grid.Row="3" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,0,0,20"  ValueChanged="sliderValueChanged"   MouseLeftButtonUp="Slider_MouseLeftButtonUp"   Name="Slider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="456" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" SmallChange="5" LargeChange="5" />`

The event sliderValueChanged takes a little time to execute. So I just want to reduce the number of calls to that event.

EDIT: Actually my problem is in child window i am drawing multiple wave forms.Without loading the waveform, the slider works fine(Empty Screen) But when ever i am loading the wave form on screen then it does not work finely.(Instead of showing continuous smooth  movement it jumps.)I am not getting what problem is actually?And how to overcome it?

Comment: Can you show your rendering code? You say it takes only 1ms to render, but that will be out of sync with the screen refresh rate (shearing etc will occur). Best call it at approximate the refresh rate (30 or 60Hz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your `sliderValueChanged` event to save the current (latest) scroll value and use a Timer to check for changes to that number on a regular basis (say 30 frame per second or 60 frames per second).

The default in Silverlight is 60 frames per second [but can be altered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838147%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The closer your updates are to the refresh rate, the smooth it will appear.

Comment: :Thanks but Actually my sliderValueChanged function takes time less than one millisecond to execute .So I dont think this solution works for me.Can you give any other solution?

Comment: What behavior do you want? Smooth updating? Smooth scrolling? You can apply any time interval to the solution above (down to about 55 milliseconds). The basic principal is to ignore unwanted extra events, but not lose the last one :)

Comment: Thanks for reply . I just want smooth scrolling of slider.And in sliderValueChanged event i am just assigning the new value to the one of the variable.No any other operation.And i am doing screen refresh after Slider_MouseLeftButtonUp event , not on sliderValueChanged  event.

Comment: Sound like it should only draw once on mouse up. Is your slider connected to the control that renders the waveform *in any way*? If so it does not need to be as you render manually (and you may be getting a clash caused by built in scrolling).

Comment: i am drawing only once on mouse up event.Can you tell me when i am sliding slider,then its render total screen again or just renders the slider internally to show new position of slider?

Comment: @Dany: It depends on how they implemented it. For inefficiency a scroll normally consists of moving as much as possible of the existing content of the screen side-ways, then just redrawing the remainder, but I have a feeling Silverlight re-renders the lot.